# How can I set the value of a field in a SELECT based on a parameter?

Tags: sql-server

What I would like is to have a SELECT that sets the value of a field called Current based on the value of the table and of two variables which are declare as inputs to a stored procedure with the select as follows:

```
DECLARE @AdminTestId INT = 111
DECLARE @UserTestId INT = null
AdminTestId      UserTestId     Current
111                             1
111                             1
222                             0
333                             0

DECLARE @AdminTestId INT = 111
DECLARE @UserTestId INT = 457
AdminTestId      UserTestId     Current
111              456            0
111              457            1
123                             0
```

Some help and advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It is very doable but not very clear. Can you give us a sample dataset and expected output based on the input parameter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got some logic where *Current* should only be set to 1 if *UserTestId* is null OR matches the UserTestId column.  You can use a case statement in your SQL query like this:

```
DECLARE @AdminTestId INT = 111
DECLARE @UserTestId INT = 457

SELECT
   AdminTestId,
   UserTestId
   CASE
     WHEN (@AdminTestId IS NULL AND @UserTestId IS NULL) THEN 0
     WHEN (@AdminTestId = AdminTestId AND @UserTestId = UserTestId) THEN 1
     WHEN (@AdminTestId = AdminTestId AND @UserTestId IS NULL) THEN 1
     WHEN (@AdminTestId IS NULL  AND @UserTestId = UserTestId) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS IsCurrent
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Just one small question. I would like to return the value with a title of Current but this gives a syntax error. I guess it's a reserved word. Is there a way I can get around this?

Comment: For reserved words, you can wrap them in square braces.  For example, SELECT something as [current].

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  ...
  CAST(CASE
    WHEN t.AdminTestID = @AdminTestID 
      AND (t.UserTestID = @UserTestID
        OR @UserTestID is NULL AND t.UserTestID is NULL)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END as bit) as Current
FROM ...
```